# return HTML/JSON with a normal JS function that contains a jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, extend

I know this "technically" can't be done as AJAX is async, but an app I'm working on has a lot of AJAX API calls and I'm trying to make this extendable for future front-end devs.

I know you can just nest everything in callbacks, but that'd be super ugly and not to mention the next dev coming along wanting to extend it wont know what to do.

So, for example, here is my code (that, *of course*, doesn't work and just returns `undefined`, but here for an example of how i'd like it to logically work):

```
var getCategories = function(type){
  var categories;
  $.get('/api/categories/all',function(json){
    if(type == 'html'){
      categories = '';
      for(x in json.data){
        categories=categories+'<option id="category_'+json.data[x].category_id+'" title="'+json.data[x].description+'">'+json.data[x].category+'</option>'
      }
    }
    else{ //JSON
      categories = json.data;
    }
    return categories;
  });
}
```

And later on a dev might want to use it in this way:
`$('div').html('<select>'+getCategories('html')+'</select>');`

How could I make this work like that? Can I with some JS trick or would every function I make like this HAVE to have a callback like, `getCategories('html',function(){})`?

If it's everything needs a callback, do you have any tips on making a mostly JS app w/ lots of AJAX calls easily extendable?

**UPDATE**

As per request, this would be a pain in the ass for a developer if he wanted to do something with, lets say, tags, categories, and posts:

```
//Some event on click
$('.button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/categories/all",
    success: function(json){
      categories = '';
      for(x in json.data){
        categories=categories+'<option id="category_'+json.data[x].category_id+'" title="'+json.data[x].description+'">'+json.data[x].category+'</option>'
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: "/api/tags/all",
        success: function(json){
          tags = '';
          for(x in json.data){
            tags=tags+'<option id="tags_'+json.data[x].category_id+'" title="'+json.data[x].description+'">'+json.data[x].category+'</option>'
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: "/api/posts/all",
            success: function(json){
              posts = '';
              for(x in json.data){
                posts=posts+'<option id="posts_'+json.data[x].category_id+'" title="'+json.data[x].description+'">'+json.data[x].category+'</option>'
              }

              //And so on...
              //after getting all this data that the developer might want
              //to put this in a modal to edit these items...
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
//On load tho, on the same page, he might want to list "popular" categories, tags, all, and he'd
//have to copy and paste the above code but change, all to popular
//Im looking to make a JS API almost to make this simpler, LIKE:
var tags = goGet('tags','popular');
var categories = gotGet('categoties','all');
//etc
```

Comment: What exactly is 'inextensible' about callbacks? We need to know what you perceive to be a problem, to suggest a solution. And yes, doing AJAX development without callbacks is like doing Java/C# without classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your examples.

You have three ajax requests in the code and none of them are dependent on each other. So, no reason to execute them sequentially.

As for `goGet`, it can also take callback easily.

```
goGet('tags','popular', function(tags) {
    // do something with tags
});
```

If you want to execute code after all data loaded, you can use counter inside.

```
var tags, categories;
var completed = 0;
goGet('tags','popular', function(entities) {
    tags = entities;
    completed++;
    if (++completed == NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS) {
        // execute your code
    }
});
goGet('categories','popular', function(entities) {
    tags = entities;
    completed++;
    if (++completed == NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS) {
        // execute your code
    }
});
```

You can generalize this callback function, to not declare it multiple times.

A bit simpler: fetch data sequentially.

```
goGet('tags','popular', function(tags) {
    goGet('categories','popular', function(categories) {
        // execute your code
    });
});
```

Comment: But the problem is, as i said in one of the examples, I need to have them be able to use it in generated source code, like, `$('.thisDoesntExistInTheDOMYet).html('<ul>'+goGet('tags','all')+</ul>') :\

Comment: The reason being, the app Im working on (not mine) contains lots of modals, and the modals contain items like, tags, categories, etc.

Comment: @OscarGodson Why not execute that in callback? It'll do exactly the same.

Comment: Err... sorry, im not explaining my issue well enough. Basically, i have a modal pop up when a user clicks a button lets say. Well, when the user clicks the button I need to go and get that stuff above, return the data, and place it in the modal which isn't actually in the DOM yet, after it grabs all the content, the modal would appear...? How could I do that?

Comment: @OscarGodson Execute your modal-creating code when all all data delivered. Or create modal with some kind of 'loading...' icon, so user knows what's going on. Then you can remove icon and populate input fields. Third option: add those data to html when page loads, so user won't have to wait. No need for ajax in this case.

Comment: @OscarGodson It's really the same with AJAX as on desktop: you just put all processing code in a callback function.